# Assign value according to interval in R

Tags: r

I have created a dataframe (called game) as shown:

```
game <- data.frame(Measure=c(50,60,70,80,90), 
                          Points=c(28,26,24,23,21))
```

[image]

When user hits measure
50-59: 28 points
60-69: 26 points
70-79: 24 points
80-89: 23 points
90 and above: 21 points

Next, I tested if result will return the correct points based on some measure.values. I used the cut function in R:

```
measure.values <- as.vector(c(50,55,60,70,77,82,95))
measure.values
result <- game$Points[cut(measure.values, c(0,game$Measure[1:4], Inf))]
```

The correct result should be 28 28 26 24 24 23 21 based on my game dataframe.
However, result currently returns [image]

I believe it is the way I index in my cut function, but I'm not sure why. Hope someone can advice me further!

Comment: look at the output of your cut function, especially the levels. You are missing the 80-90 category. Moreover, the first level from your cut is 0-50 while in your `game` the first is 50-60.

Comment: You might want to use `labels = FALSE`. Then you will get an integer vector from cut instead of a factor. You can then index `game$Points` with that. See `?cut`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of doing this is with `dplyr::case_when()` which lets us specify multiple conditions and provide a value as an output.

The below is an example of this and a function to make this easier for you.

```r
library(dplyr)

x <- c(50,55,60,70,77,82,95)

case_when(
  between(x, 50, 59) ~ 28,
  between(x, 60, 69) ~ 26,
  between(x, 70, 79) ~ 24,
  between(x, 80, 89) ~ 23,
  x >= 90 ~ 21
)


score_measure <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    between(x, 50, 59) ~ 28,
    between(x, 60, 69) ~ 26,
    between(x, 70, 79) ~ 24,
    between(x, 80, 89) ~ 23,
    x >= 90 ~ 21
  )
}

score_measure(45:100)
```

Comment: hi! i use cut as my actual dataframe has more than 15 intervals and would hence have many between() if i were to use case_when. is there a way to generate multiple intervals of fixed sizes instead of doing it manually?

Comment: by intervals of fixed sizes, i mean the intervals are [50,60),[60,70),[70,80),...[170,180),[180,190), 190 and above

Comment: Indeed, `cut` is right and `case_when` is inappropriate here.

Comment: @newtocodingyikes ah that's helpful. I'm still unclear what the range of these intervals are and how you assign points. But you can create your desired breaks with code like `cut(0:999, breaks = seq(0, 99999, by = 10), include.lowest = TRUE)`. I would avoid using `Inf` as your upperbound because it would never end lol